# How to use bash command substitution in grub for clonezilla postrun?

Tags: bash, grub2, clonezilla

I am in the process of configuring unattended backup with `grub` and `Clonezilla Live` image. Auto-mounting the image target dir works, and so does the backup itself.

But with `ocs_postrun`, I would like to copy the log files to the target as well, using the current date as foldername.

So I try to achieve on the Clonezilla Live system:

```
cp /var/log /home/partimag/log
mv /home/partimag/log /home/partimag/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%HM-log")
```

which I added in `grub` as:

```
ocs_postrun="cp /var/log /home/partimag/log"
ocs_postrun1="mv /home/partimag/log /home/partimag/\$(date +\"%Y-%m-%d-%HM-log\")"
```

Copying the logfiles works fine, but renaming it with `date` and bash command substitution fails.

I also tried:

```
ocs_postrun1="sudo bash \'mv /home/partimag/log /home/partimag/\$(date +\"%Y-%m-%d-%HM-log\")\'"
```

I believe it might be an issue with my escaping the characters `$` and `"` within the bash command.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

PS: `grub-install --version` returns `2.02+dfsg1-20+deb10u4`

Comment: You probably do need to escape inner double quotes so you're not terminating the outer quotes too early, but I'm not sure why you are escaping the `$`.  Have you tried it without the backslash before the `$`?

Comment: @chicks I did try without escaping `$`, but then `grub-mkconfig` complains about a syntax error.

Comment: Can you put the commands in a script file and put that script in the ocs_postrun1 paramater?

Comment: @chicks that might be a workaround, but I would prefer having everything in one place (the grub config).

Comment: OK, it works with calling an external script for `ocs_postrun`. Still would be interested to know how to achieve this entirely in `grub.cfg`, though.

Comment: It seems like the grub.cfg does not have full shell functionality so I think this is the best way to do it.